# Inaccessible function error + virtual

Tags: c#, inheritance, virtual

I have the below scenario:

```
 public class T1
    {
        protected virtual int add()
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public class T2 : T1
    {       
    }

    public class T3 : T2
    {
        protected override int add()
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            T1 t1 = new T3();            

            ((T3)t1).add();

        }
    }
```

however, in the line that call to add function ((T3)t1).add();
i am get error T3.add() is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: You could call protected method only  inside of the class or derived class, but you try to call it from outside of the class.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx)

> The protected keyword is a member access modifier. A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

You can't access `protected` method from another class. It need to be `public`.

```
public class T1
{
    public virtual int add()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class T2 : T1
{       
}

public class T3 : T2
{
    public override int add()
    {
        return 3;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        T1 t1 = new T3();            

        ((T3)t1).add();

    }
}
```